# rails - require single file works, but require all of directory not

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Requires single file is working fine:

```
require Rails.root.join('lib/railsadmin_custom_functions', 'drive_clear.rb')
```

--

Now I'm trying to automate and require all files on the same folder:

```
Dir[Rails.root.join('lib/railsadmin_custom_functions')].each {|file| require file }
```

So I'm getting this error:

```
dependencies.rb:229:in `require': cannot load such file -- /Users/me/projects/myproject/lib/railsadmin_custom_functions (LoadError)
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code for load `railsadmin_custom_functions` as a file.

`'lib/railsadmin_custom_functions'`

change to

`'lib/railsadmin_custom_fuctions/*.extention_of_files'`

Try this

```
Dir["#{Rails.root}/lib/railsadmin_custom_functions/*.rb"].each {|file| require file }
```

or

```
Dir.glob("#{Rails.root}/lib/railsadmin_custom_functions/*.rb")
```

output

```
=> ["/Users/me/projects/myproject/lib/railsadmin_custom_functions/file1.rb", "/Users/me/projects/myproject/lib/railsadmin_custom_functions/file2.rb"]
```

Or try this, if you want to require files in all folders and files in subfolders

```
Dir.glob("#{Rails.root}/lib/railsadmin_custom_functions/**/*.rb")
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to skip `.` and `..`, which are entries of a directory listing. You might also want tn check if the entry is a directory and skip them as well:

```
Dir[Rails.root.join('lib/railsadmin_custom_functions')].each do |file|
  next if File.directory?(file)
  require file
end
```

Comment: don't understand. can you give some example?